# How do I limit the amount of times a JMS DefaultMessageListenerContainer will retry a message in ActiveMQ?

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic

How do I limit the amount of times a JMS DefaultMessageListenerContainer will retry a message with SpringBoot and ActiveMQ.( I know we can achieve this using  JMSXDeliveryCount property in IBM MQ messageListener).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach is to use the `RedeliveryPolicy` available in for ActiveMQ. To use it with spring boot, you could enable it as query params on the Broker URL.

`tcp://localhost:61616?jms.redeliveryPolicy.maximumRedeliveries=5`

You can tweak other features, such as time between redelivery etc with the options described in [activemq.apache.org/redelivery-policy.html](http://activemq.apache.org/redelivery-policy.html).